# Should I ventilate a heated attic?

Tags: roof, ventilation

A lot of guidance I have read on attic venting seems to assume people have crawlspace attics that are not living space. Here is a typical illustration:

[image]

My attic is living space and I do not have (nor will I add) insulation on the floor of the attic, because it is heated space and receives that heat from the floor below. My attic has stairs leading up to it and a window. I definitely do not want to prevent it from being heated.

So, in that case should it still be ventilated? I do not have a vent at the peak of the roof. If I did have a peak, it would lead to significant heat loss in the non-summer months. I live in New England.

Comment: No more than you'd ventilate any other habitable room. You essentially have a "hot roof" (assuming that the rafter cavities are insulated).

Comment: I would build and insulate just as the picture you included shows. The insulation would be in the walls and ceiling of the living space. The sealed part of the attic needs to be vented but not the living space.